# Breaking down numbers to $2$'s and $3$'s

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing

How can I prove that all numbers greater than 3 could be written as a sum of $2$'s and $3$'s only?

Comment: Hint: can there be a smallest number that can't be written as sum of 2s and 3s?

Comment: Can you see that once you have two consecutive numbers which can be written in this way, all the rest can?

Comment: Every even greater than $3$ can be written $2+2+\dots+2$.  Every odd greater than $3$ can be written $3+2+2+\dots+2$.  These can be phrased as straightforward induction proofs.

Comment: Of course... there are in fact *many* different ways a particular number can be written as a sum of $2$'s or $3$'s, but that doesn't matter to us.  As a fun challenge though, you might try revisiting this problem later once you have learned about recurrence relations to see if you can come up with an expression for the *number of ways* a number $n$ can be written as a sum of $2$'s or $3$'s http://oeis.org/A182097

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $n$ be a number, $n>3$. There are only two possibilities, either $n$ is even or odd. If $n$ is even, then $\exists\;k$, s.t. $2k=n$. Then it is clear that, $n$ can be written as sum of $k$ twos. On the other hand, if $n$ is odd, then $\exists\;l$, s.t. $2l+1=n\Rightarrow 2(l-1)+3=n$. Then it is clear that, $n$ can be written as sum of $l-1$ twos, and one $3$.

Note that numbers $1$ and $3$ can't be written as sum of $2$ and $3$. That is why the condition greater than $3$  is needed.